# How to disable editing of image component on page editor?

Tags: image, sitecore, page-editor

I have an image component for which I need to disable its editing ribbon on Sitecore Page Editor so that the author is unable to edit/change the image.

In code:

```xml
<sc:Image Field="Image" ID="Image1" runat="server">
```

I have tried `DisableWebEditing="true"` but of no use !

Also tried this in code behind

```csharp
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
{
    Image1.DisableWebEditing = true;
}`
```

How do i disable the image editing?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have expected the change you have made to work in disabling the web edit functionality. Are you testing as an "is administrator" functionality? I know that Page Editor will occasionally provide full admins more access.

If you do not want it to ever be edited, you can also consider use an ASP.NET image control and updating it with the data from the media item.

Comment: Hi Jay. Yes, i am testing as an administrator. Is it possible to single out each button and then disable them ?

Comment: I would recommend creating an author test user and logging in to verify if the code you have done is already working. I would have expected the code you have used already to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try testing as you suggest. :-)

Comment: The code is working properly for sc:Image. However, I have a custom image component which is using picturefillimage.js for responsive display and somehow the image edit buttons are enabled even if DisableWebEditing="true" .

Comment: I'm glad your sc:image code is working! You may need to start a new question about your custom image component and post some of the code so that the folks here can see where the issue is.